# Populate a field using mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build query in a nodejs / mongoose project using mongoDB's aggregation framework but I can't get `$lookup` to work.

I have two collections, a project schema:

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  contact: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Contact',
    required: true,
  },
  ...
export default mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

and a contact schema:

```
const contactSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  some fields
  ...
export default mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);
```

In `project.contact` I store the `_id` of the contact document.
I can populate the project with the contact data when doing e.g. this:

```
Project.find().populate('contact')
```

But I only get an empty array for `contactData` when I build a query using aggregation like this:

```
const history = await Project.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Contact',
      localField: 'contact',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'contactData',
    },
  },
]);
```

I want to have access to the whole contact-document for further processing but I do not want to store the whole contact document in the project collection.

Shouldn't this work, or am I missing something here...?

Comment: `from: 'contact',`

Comment: @AlexBlex: I've tried this before, but no luck

Comment: The `from` value is the name of the contact collection not model name. It should be `contacts`. So you can try `from: 'contacts'` to see if it helps.

Comment: @Veeram: You are right, it must be the name of the COLLECTION not the name of the model! So it's `contacts`. Thanks for that!